Inconsistent wording in Birkot Hashachar?
Many of the blessings in Birkot Hashachar do not use the definitive article (letter ה) when ascribing an action to G-d. For example:
...בָּרוּךְ אַתָּה יְהֹוָה אֱלֹהֵֽינוּ מֶֽלֶךְ הָעוֹלָם

מַלְבִּישׁ עֲרֻמִּים - Who clothes the naked.
מַתִּיר אֲסוּרִים - Who releases the imprisoned.
זוֹקֵף כְּפוּפִים - Who straightens the bent.

But some of the blessings do:
...בָּרוּךְ אַתָּה יְהֹוָה אֱלֹהֵֽינוּ מֶֽלֶךְ הָעוֹלָם

הַמֵּכִין מִצְעֲדֵי גָֽבֶר - Who prepares the steps of man.

הַנּוֹתֵן לַיָּעֵף כֹּֽחַ - Who gives strength to the weary.

הַמַּעֲבִיר שֵׁנָה מֵעֵינָי וּתְנוּמָה מֵעַפְעַפָּי - Who removes sleep from my eyes and slumber from my eyelids.


Is there any reason for this?

This phenomenon is not just in these blessings but all over. המוציא לחם and הפורס סוכת שלום but בורא פרי and גאל ישראל

מֵּכִין מִצְעֲדֵי גָֽבֶר sounds wrong. הַמַלְבִּישׁ הַעֲרֻמִּים also sounds wrong. There are some complicated rules about when the ה can be dropped, also stylistic rules. See https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Ketubot.2a.1.1?vhe=Vilna_Edition&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he for eg

@RabbiKaii המלביש ערומים sounds correct to me.

@shmosel sounds unusual at least, as that ה is dropped a lot

@RabbiKaii Definitely sounds wrong, because my minhag is אשר הכין מצעדי גבר! Jokes aside, it seems to me that the longer ones are treated as clauses and get the ה.

related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31310/what-is-the-difference-between-for-example-notein-and-hanotein

Regarding המוציא לחם see Gemara Berachos Daf לח

We say מלך אוהב צדקה ומשפט but המלך המשפט

I notice a pattern here: Phrases consisting of two words have the ה dropped, while longer phrases don’t. If not a coincidence, this could be relevant to the answer.

@J.W.Tanner I’m not familiar enough with dikduk lingo to articulate it, but I’m under the impression that המלך המשפט is a grammatical oddity to begin with.

@Qwertrl it's not a coincidence, as Kazi bácsi said, the longer phrases are relative clauses, so they need the ה, but the participle in the shorter ones is acting as a verb so can drop the ה, and is still determinate. הַנּוֹתֵן לַיָּעֵף כֹּֽחַ or נּוֹתֵן כֹּֽחַ but not נּוֹתֵן לַיָּעֵף כֹּֽחַ. See also the tosafot I quoted for more information about why we do drop the ה when we don't need to

@Yø-cRo see Tosafot on  העבד העברי https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Ketubot.2a.1.1?vhe=Vilna_Edition&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he

@RabbiKaii Interesting! However in those cases the second word is qualifying the first, whereas המלך המשפט seems akin to saying ״המלך המדינה״

@RabbiKaii אוזר ישראל בגבורה, עוטר ישראל בתפארה both don't for that rule, I assume there are others

@Loani I don't think those are exceptions, עוטר and אוזר are acting as present finite verbs and don't need the ה. They are not introducing relative clauses, just acting on ישראל. I'm not an expert, I've been starting with what limited dikduk experience, and ideas I have, to ask certain people I know questions, and use a bit of cautious help from ChatGPT. It seems it's a hard question overall, even Israeli's are finding it hard to answer

Related (duplicate?): "Why the change in phrase with the morning blessings?"

Which aspect are you emphasizing as not consistent? Why must they be consistent in this way?

There is a tradition that the “identifying Heh” is making reference to specific usage in the written Torah. The מצעדי גבר to Mishlei 20:24, the ליעף כח to Devarim 25:18, Shemot 17:11, and שנה מעיני to Bereshit 31:40.

IMHO the simplest explanation is that these blessings developed independently and organically over time and therefore reflected conventional phrasing and usages at the time/place it originally emerged... looking for a unifying rule (or rather crafting one) will therefore more likely be something like shooting an arrow and drawing a bullseye around it.

I'll give this a quick go, based on my research so far. I'll say though, I've asked around, including a few native Israeli Rabbis, and all are finding it hard to answer. I've also used a bit of cautious help from ChatGPT :)
The longer phrases have relative clauses, so the participle is introducing the relative clause. Therefore it must retain the ה
In the shorter ones it is acting as a finite verb, and therefore it can drop the ה, because it is clear the two words are connected and are determined. See this tosafot for a partial discussion on when the Torah does drop these הs, and why. Generally, it does tend to drop them often, and it sounds weird when it does not (hence this tosafot).
